# Passing a block into a method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to work out how you pass blocks into methods.

Basically I have a method, and instead of having the user write this:

```
def user_config
    @config[:config_value] = "what they want"
end
```

I'd like them to be able to do this:

```
user_config do
    :config_value => "what they want"
end
```

But I dont know how to work with a block in the method.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question, but why would your user ever *define* the method? Also, the block version looks pretty much like the user is simply passing in a simple hash. So why not do that rather than a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks are invoked with yield, so this:

```
def user_config
    yield.each do |k, v|
        @config[k] = v
    end
end
```

called like this

```
user_config do
    {:config_value => "what they want"}
end
```

should work as you want it to. The block returns

```
{:config_value => "what they want"}
```

You take the each key in the hash and asign its value in the @config hash.

Answer (score 3):

Although @diegogs is right and his solution will work just fine, I'd avoid using blocks in such a simple case.

```
def user_config(config_hash)
  config_hash.each do |k,v|
    @config[k] = v
  end
end
```

will do just fine

```
user_config :config_value => "what they want", ...
```

How about that?

Comment: the example is a little dummbed down, and there is allot of potential config for the gem, so a block would be more suited.

Comment: Also forgot to mention this is how im doing it now